# If $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,\infty)$,and $f'$ has definition on $[a,\infty)$,can one deduce that $f'$ is bounded?

Tags: calculus

If $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,\infty)$,and $f'$ has definition on $[a,\infty)$,can one deduce that $f'$ is bounded on $[a,\infty)$?

I know some functions like $\sqrt{x}$ which has definition on the open set $(0,\infty)$ , but which derivative is not bounded, so I wish the boundedness will be hold on a closed set $[a,\infty)$

Answer (score 3):

Al you need is a continuous integrable unbounded function $g$ on $[a,\infty)$ and define $f(x)=\int_a^{x} g(t)\, dt$. Can you think of such a function?.

Hint: draw a triangle with base $(n-\frac 1 {n^{3}},n+\frac 1 {n^{3}})$ with height $n$.  Think of a contnuous functions whose graph is made up of the 'other two sides' of the triangle for $n=1,2...$.

Comment: thank you I got it .